# Routes in CodeIgniter: Matching specific length segment

Tags: regex, codeigniter

I'm trying to catch and re-route all urls that start with a set string and then contain a segment of exactly 5 characters.

i.e. website.com/coupon/**X1OPA**

Struggling to find an example of how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This did the trick

```
$route['coupon/([a-zA-Z0-9]{5})']   = 'coupon/apply_code/$1';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following regular expression:

```
website.com\/coupon\/\w{5}
```

or

```
website.com\/coupon\/\w{5}$
```

- {5}: exactly 5 copies of previous regular expression should be matched.
- {m,n}: m ~ n copies of previous regular expresison should be matched.